# What is a secretion target family protein?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, bacteriology, bacterial-toxins

I came across this link: https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?btw:BF38_3398
What is this protein, is it a secreted effector protein or is it something else?

What is the difference between type VII secretion protein (https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?sams:NI36_12950) and type VII secretion effector (https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?bmyo:BG05_3891)?

Comment: Have you followed up the links you get from an internet search for type VII secretion? I know nothing about the topic, which sounds quite specialized, but reckon I could hack it in a quarter of an hour. Or is the problem journal access?

Comment: @David yes I have tried to find the difference between the two types of proteins but could not find any proper explanation....